# Geolocalizar la tweets en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, twitter-api

Estoy intentanto realizar una geolocalización de tweets usando la API de twitter, estoy usando un stream de tipo statuses/filter para consultar los tweets, y el dato de posición estoy sacandolo de coordiantes, pero al consultar me devuelve unicamente la posición de muy pocos tweets, existe otra manera de poder consultar la posición. 
Asi es como lo hago ahora.

```
client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: criteria },  function(stream) {
        stream.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);  
        });
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
             jsonTweet = {
                    "id": data.id,
                    "user":"@" + data.user.screen_name,
                    "date": data.timestamp_ms,
                    "name": data.name,
                    "text": prep(data.text),
                    "language": data.lang,
                    "coordinates": data.coordinates
                        }
                      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay forma de obtener más resultados (o mejor dicho, no hay cómo poner ubicación a tweets sin posición) pero lo que sí puedes hacer es, por ejemplo, filtrar por un array de coordenadas (bounding box) lo suficientemente amplio como para abarcar toda la zona que te interesa:

```
client.stream('statuses/filter', {
        locations: [-130, -57, -60, 0]
    },  function(stream) {
    ...
    }
);
```

En este caso los tweets sin posición no podrían cumplir con el parámetro locations, por lo que no vendrían en el resultado.

Si usas este método, y además quieres hacer track por un determinado término, no va a funcionar, porque ese criterio se cumple para los tweets **que cumplan con el término o que estén en el rango de locations**. O sea, es una cláusula OR.

Un dato adicional: si especificas locations, te van a llegar tweets que cumplan con una de las dos condiciones:

1. Tweets con coordenadas (que estén dentro del bounding box)
2. Tweets **que tengan el atributo place** y cuyo bounding box se superponga con tu bounding box.

Dado que un tweet tenga bounding box, entonces puedes geolocalizar el tweet al centro del bounding box.

En otras palabras, dado un criterio locations, los tweets que vengan tendrán coordenadas o tendrán place, y los geolocalizarías como:

```
if (data.coordinates) {
    jsonTweet = {
      "id": data.id,
      "user":"@" + data.user.screen_name,
      "date": data.timestamp_ms,
      "name": data.name,
      "text": prep(data.text),
      "language": data.lang,
      "coordinates": data.coordinates
    };
} else if (data.place && data.place.bounding_box) {

    var SW = data.place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0],
        NE = data.place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][2];

    data.coordinates = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [(SW[0] + NE[0]) / 2, (SW[1] + NE[1]) / 2]
    };

    jsonTweet = {
      "id": data.id,
      "user":"@" + data.user.screen_name,
      "date": data.timestamp_ms,
      "name": data.name,
      "text": prep(data.text),
      "language": data.lang,
      "coordinates": data.coordinates
    };

}
```

Más información en [Stream API #Locations](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#locations)